# How do I use TreeView.Resources HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType to specify a Dictionary<string, List<T>>?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a list of OBJs, that I've stored into `List<OBJ> OBJS` property, and I've created a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the Data, which works (see below).

```
 <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityType:Projectiles}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                      Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.Resources>
```

Which gave me the below TreeView:

- Projectile A
- Projectile B
- Projectile C
- Particle A
- Particle B
- Particle C

However, because my data is actually a `List` of `OBJ`, there are child classes that are in that same list, I wanted to group the classes under its own `Type`. i.e. `new List<OBJ>() { new Projectiles(), new Particles() }` should have a *node* for `Projectiles`, `Particles`, etc. I created a `Converter` that changes it into a `Dictionary`, which then doesn't work with the above `HierarchicalDataTemplate` because it is now a `Dictionary<string, List<OBJ>`.

I then created a new `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that handled the `Dictionary<string, List<OBJ>`, see below.

```
 <TreeView Name="MyTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding OBJS, 
           Converter={StaticResource ItemsSourceConverter}}"
 <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
 </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

And the `Converter`:

```
 class ItemsSourceConverter : IValueConverter {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
           List<OBJ> objs = new List<OBJ>(value as List<OBJ>);
           var query = (from a in objs
                          group a by a.GetType() into b
                          select new {
                               EntityName = b.Key.ToString().Split('.').Last().Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + b.Key.ToString().Split('.').Last().Substring(1).ToLower(),
                               Entities = b.OrderBy(a=>a.retrieveName()).ToList()
                          }).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.EntityName, kvp => kvp.Entities);
           return query;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
           return null;
      }
 }
```

Which gave me the below TreeView, creating the proper groups:

- Projectiles
- Particles

But expanding them would give me the following two errors for each node inside `Particles` or `Projectiles`.

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Value' property not found on 'object' 'Projectiles' (HashCode=37857370)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value; DataItem='Projectiles' (HashCode=37857370); target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found on 'object' 'Projectiles' (HashCode=37857370)'. BindingExpression:Path=Key; DataItem='Projectiles' (HashCode=37857370); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

It seems that once you set `TreeView.ItemTemplate`, it ignores all the `DataTemplates` that you have defined in `TreeView.Resources`?

In my first attempt, I was able to use `DataType="{x:Type EntityType:Projectiles}"` to specify that I wanted the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to be used for `Projectiles` objects, is there a `DataType` syntax that will let me specify `DataType="{x:Type Dictionary<string, List<OBJ>>}"`? So I can do something like the below?

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                           DataType="{x:Type Dictionary<string, List<OBJ>>}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

That way, in the end, I'll have the below:

- Projectiles

  - Projectile A
  - Projectile B
  - Projectile C
- Particles

  - Particle A
  - Particle B
  - Particle C

Edit: This should also work if I have sub-levels, see below.

- Projectiles

  - Projectile SubType A

    - Projectile A
  - Projectile SubType B

    - Projectile B
    - Projectile C
- Particles

  - Particle A
  - Particle B
  - Particle C

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want the projectile node to have particle and projectile child nodes and the particle node to have particle and projectile child nodes. Is this correct?

Comment: @Killingsworth No no, sorry. It should be a node for `Projectiles`, then in `Items`, it'll have the names of the `Projectiles`. I'll add what it should finally end up being.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Sample classes:

```
class OBJ
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Projectiles : OBJ {}

class Particles : OBJ {}
```

Sample data initialization:

```
List<OBJ> _source = new List<OBJ>() 
    {
        new Projectiles{ Name = "Projectile A"},
        new Projectiles{ Name = "Projectile B"},
        new Projectiles{ Name = "Projectile C"},
        new Particles { Name = "Particle A"},
        new Particles { Name = "Particle B"},
        new Particles { Name = "Particle C"},
    };

var query = (from a in _source
             group a by a.GetType() into b
             select new
             {
                 EntityName = b.Key.ToString().Split('.').Last().Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + b.Key.ToString().Split('.').Last().Substring(1).ToLower(),
                 Entities = b.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList()
             }).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.EntityName, kvp => kvp.Entities);

treeView1.DataContext = query;
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that when I expand `Projectile` etc. into sub-types it'll work too? It looks like it only works with one level, and not sub-levels. i.e. Projectiles -> Projectiles Type A. I've updated the proposed final result, I know I can just set the DataTemplate inside a Hierarchical, but what happens if there is another level under that? I don't want to have to copy/paste and it wouldnt work if there isn't a sub-level.